# Как имитировать звучание струн гитары?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Здраствуйте. Мне нужно написать эмулятор гитары. Можете посоветовать какие-либо библиотеки (`.NET`) или даже где просто можно взять сэмплы нот для всех гитарных октав (файл со звуком ноты)? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: в качестве извращения могу посоветовать взять тот же fruity loops(FL Studio), ну и там на гитаре нарезать себе сэмплов), ну это если вы любите изврат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. Что вам дадут семплы? Гитарные звуки - достаточно сложная штука, особенно звук перегруженной гитары, его до сих пор не могут нормально эмулировать. Я бы вам посоветовал копать в сторону `MIDI`. Т.е. для начала разобраться, как алгоритмически заставить Вашу программу проигрывать заданную мелодию, потом подцепить к ней нужный инструмент из какого-нибудь `MIDI` банка.

Для затравки вот несколько ссылок:

- [Описание формата MIDI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI).
- [Пример приложения, работающего с MIDI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit).